# running total per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate a running total per 10min for cost  each shift, and the total resets to 0 at the end of the shift

this query is what I have now.

```
select shift,
floor(unix_timestamp(date)/600) window, 
    (select sum(cost) 
    from expenses 
    where shift = S.shift AND id < max(S.id))
from expenses S 
group by shift, window, order by window desc
having window > ?
```

this table has something like 16million rows, and this query takes really long to run, is there any way of optimizing it?

Comment: i wonder how the query even runs with a `max` in `where`. are you sure you posted the correct query?

Comment: Really having a hard time visualizing your data here, can you post a sample table and your desired output.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala It works because that max if for a column of the outer query not the sub.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query